# Optimal binary search Tree - TimeComplexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, pseudocode

[image]

So what really made me stumble here is that when i were to try and calculate the time complexity of this algorithm i was confused by the fact that there are 3 loops which would lead me to believe the operations are O(n^3) but the thing is the middle loop decreases as the outer loop increases and the most inner loop increases as the middle loop decreases. I would pretty much guess it's an O(n^2) overall algorithm but it still seems to be O(n^3) because of the 3 nested loops. 
When counting the number of operations while running the code i get a counting of somewhere inbetween O(n^2) and O(n^3) which makes it all more frustrating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried something, I would like to hear some fixes it's been some time since my algorithm course :)

[image: Time complexity solving]

> The Sigma is for every loop. notice how it's becoming a multiply when
>   there is no dependency on the variable

Comment: The last step doesn't seem right: `Sigma (n-d)(d+1) = n Sigma (d+1) - Sigma d(d+1)`. The first term amounts to `(n^3)/2`, the second one to `(n^3)/3`, and the cubes do not vanish.

Comment: The point was really well made enough with this post to understand the concept which was the main goal with the post, I believe most people will figure out the last step and therefore i will assign this as the answer. Thank you very much for the help!